# How to return Json with Multiple properties by using ResponseEntity in Spring RestController

Tags: spring, spring-restcontroller

I am writing rest services for learning in Spring. I want to return dynamic responses(Json with multiple properties) from controller. For example I have a method where I am returning list of Products and Spring by default using message converter convert it into Json. It is working fine.

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> greet(@PathVariable Optional<Integer> productId) {

    List<Products> products = productService.findAllCategories();
    int count = products.size(); // also want to include this as count like below response
    return new ResponseEntity<List<Products>>(products, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Now I want response Json like this one

```
{
  "count": 23,
  "products":[
     {..},
     {..}
   ]
}
```

Count show list count.How I return response like this. Or guide me to the best practices for scenario like returning Json with multiple properties.

Comment: create wrapper of it and set both the count and products property into another bean and replace List<Products> with new bean ProductsDto as like done by @satya-j below.

Comment: @TechnoCrat Let suppose I have another model Customers and I want the same thing then I have to make another  wrapper and so on for other models also. I need a generic solution so that at runtime I can return Json with any format.

Comment: in that case you only need to add new property into ProductsDTO class with List<Customer> as like below

class ProductsDTO {
  private int count;
  private List<Products> products;
  private List<Customers> customers;
}

Comment: Basically I want to do something like this. response.add("count", count);
response.add("products", products); response.add("something", something);

Comment: You can go with solution provided by @Valath or you need to add new property as i suggest. this is not possible i guess and also it will not look good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done through this but I don't know it is good practice or not.

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/{productId}", "" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> greet(@PathVariable Optional<Integer> productId) {
    List<Products> products = productService.findAllCategories();

    HashMap<String, Object> hmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    hmap.put("count", products.size());
    hmap.put("products", products);
    // Now I can put as many properties as I want

    return new ResponseEntity<HashMap<String, Object>>(hmap, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: It works if you add Jackson to your project. I would suggest you to refer this - https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson and some additional references. I've updated my answer with a sample code with jackson

Answer (score 6):

Little more improvement can achieve what you are looking for.

Create a wrapper for the products. Something like

```
class ProductsDTO {

  private int count;
  private List<Products> products;

  /* create setters and getters for the fields */ 

}
```

and then in your REST call

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> greet(@PathVariable Optional<Integer> productId) {

List<Products> products = productService.findAllCategories();
int count = products.size();
ProductsDTO productsDTO = new ProductsDTO(); 
productsDTO.setCount(count);
productsDTO.setProducts(products);
return new ResponseEntity<ProductsDTO>(productsDTO, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**EDIT:**

**@Shams Tabraiz Alam**
- Not sure if the kind of result that you wanted to form is correct way, because when you say count and list, it perfectly makes sense that you're returning and list of entity(product) and it's count **result[count of products, list of products]**. Not sure exactly the purpose of adding additional data as it removes actual meaning of returning list and it's count as result. Anyway that's my point.

For your situation, if you don't want to use DTO and use a map to add as many properties as you want, I've made a sample code(maven way)

Add Spring and other existing dependencies, then add Jackson dependencies to **pom.xml**

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.5</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.5</version>
  </dependency>
```

And have a REST Controller,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/locations", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> getAll() {
    List<Location> locations  = locationService.getLocations();
    List<Country> countries = countryService.getCountries();

    Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    result.put("count",locations.size());
    result.put("locations",locations);
    result.put("countries",countries);
    // Add any additional props that you want to add
    return new ResponseEntity<Map<String,Object>>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Build and deploy the code in your local web server(port 8080) OR run through command line using maven - **mvn tomcat7:run**

Test it..

1. Command line -

   ```
    curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X GET http://localhost:8080/api/locations
   ```
2. Browser

http://localhost:8080/api/locations

Full code is here - https://github.com/satya-j/loco

Comment: Let suppose I have another model Customers and I want the same thing then I have to make another class with CustomersDTO and so on for other models also. I need a generic solution.

Comment: @ShamsTabraizAlam You are specific in your question to return {count:23, **products**:[]}. I answered in that aspect. If you wish to go for generic solution for the above like you wish to return **result(count,list of objects)**, you need to model it in your code.

Comment: If you need a generic solution, please make an interface X. Let all the classes which you want to send to response extend this X. Modify your response class with properties: count and List<X>. So you can get assign count and any type of X to your response class.

Comment: @ satya-j  I just gave an example to demonstrate. I need something like this  response.add("count", count); response.add("products", products); response.add("something", something);
and at the end return response.

Comment: @ShamsTabraizAlam You wish to have count of that "something" also included in **count** ?

Comment: this should be the right answer with complicating things thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class RestApiController {
    @Autowired
    RepoCity repoCity;

    @Autowired
    RepoCountry repoCountry;

    @Autowired
    RepoLanguage repoLanguage;

    @GetMapping("/allTotal")
    public Map actionAllTotal() {
        Map map = new HashMap();
        map.put("repoCity",repoCity.count());
        map.put("repoCountry",repoCountry.count());
        map.put("repoLanguage",repoLanguage.count());
        Map result = new HashMap();;
        result.put("result",map);
        return result;
    }

    @GetMapping("/country-detail/{id}")
    public Map actionCountryDetail(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
        Map result = new HashMap();
        result.put("result",repoCountry.findOne(id));
        return result;
    }
}
```

> Output

[image]

Comment: Rendering multiple Enity json key value

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{pid}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces =  MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> greet(@PathVariable(value = "pid", required = false) Integer productId) {
  Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String,Object>();
  result.put("count",locations.size());
  result.put("locations",locations);
  result.put("countries",countries);

  return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
}
```