# Spring Boot API - POST complete data from client

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, api

I have the task to implement an API with Spring Boot and a relational database to save the data from a client (mobile app) and synchronize it.
So far no problem. I have some endpoints to post and get the stored data.

Now I have the task to provide an endpoint that return the complete data in a GET-Request and another to save the complete data of the client via a POST-Request.

My problem is:

1. How do I store the complete data in one POST-Request(JSON)? 
   The database has multiple entities with manytomany relationships and if I just POST them then I have some problems with the relations between the Entities.
2. My approach to GET the complete data was to just create a new Entity with every entity in it. Is this the best solution?

And is this even a good solution to POST the complete data instead of the usage of the other endpoints to get the entities one by one. Or is there another approach to store and restore the complete data from server and client? Whereby I think that posting the complete data makes less sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is this even a good solution to POST the complete data instead of the usage of the other endpoints to get the entities one by one

In some scenarios you may want to force update or synchronize the client data with the server, for example, WhatsApp backup now option.

> How do I store the complete data in one POST-Request(JSON)

You can make one post endpoint that extracts the data sent from the client and internally use all your repositories or daos for each property.

> My approach to GET the complete data was to just create a new Entity
>   with every entity in it. Is this the best solution

either by doing as you mentioned or by handling it manually in the endpoint like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47469837/8458501)

also check this [one](https://technology.amis.nl/2019/08/09/apache-camel-and-spring-boot-calling-multiple-services-in-parallel-and-merging-results/) which uses apache camel to aggregate multiple endpoints

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. A break and your answer helped me a lot.

Comment: it's my pleasure :)